# Python generated QRcode containing a vCard opens as text on Android devices

Tags: python, android, qr-code

A friend asked me to create a QRCode which will "Create new Contact". I used Python and it works like a charm on all iOS devices. Android whatsoever has an issue. It opens some kind of Text Editor and pastes the vCard data into it. Many different Customers on all kind of Devices had the same issue.

```
import qrcode
from PIL import Image
# import base64

# Create vCard data
vcard = {
    "surname": "surname",
    "lastname": "lastname",
    "organisation": "company name",
    "mobile": "+4912312321312",
    "office": "+4912313131313",
    "address": "teststreet 13, 12345 testcity",
    "mail": "test@test.com",
    "website": "https://www.test.com/",
}

# Construct vCard text
vcard_text = f"""
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:{vcard["lastname"]};{vcard["surname"]}
ORG:{vcard["organisation"]}
TEL;TYPE=voice,work,pref:{vcard["office"]}
TEL;TYPE=voice,mobile,pref:{vcard["mobile"]}
ADR:{vcard["address"]}
EMAIL:{vcard["mail"]}
URL:{vcard["website"]}
END:VCARD
"""

# Generate QR code
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
    box_size=10,
    border=2,
)
qr.add_data(vcard_text)
qr.make(fit=True)

# Create an image from the QR code
qr_img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white").convert('RGB')

## Load and add a logo to the QR code
## logo_path = "company_logo.jpg"  # Path to your logo image
## logo = Image.open(logo_path)
## set size of QR code
## pos = ((qr_img.size[0] - logo.size[0]) // 2,
##  (qr_img.size[1] - logo.size[1]) // 2)
## qr_img.paste(logo, pos)

# Save the QR code image
qr_img.save("vcard50.png")
```

For me sounds like an issue that Android interprets the qrcode different then iOS. While researching I found out that some people have similar issues when exporting vCards out of adobe products. But I did it from scratch. Any ideas?